# List local branches after project reinstallation

Tags: git, version-control

I have worked on a particular branch, then had to delete project locally (because of Xcode crash) and now, after cloning the project again from bitbucket repo, I want to list local branches so that I checkout on branch I've been working previously (as I don't remember its name)

How is that possible?

Comment: On a new clone, the only local branch you will have is probably `master`. Do you actually mean all remote branches?

Comment: no, because I haven't pushed that branch I'm looking for

Comment: If you deleted the old working copy, anything that wasn't pushed is lost.

Comment: `git branch` will list all local branches, and `git branch -a` will list all branches.

Comment: the thing is project is deleted and the only local branch is master 
:(

Comment: But if I remember the branch name, it's already lost ?

Comment: If you deleted the folder and made a new clone, it's gone.

Comment: you can use `git branch -a` to list remote branches, then `git fetch` command which will fetch all the branches for local checkout and then use `git checkout <branchname>` command to checkout remote branch to local